# How to output updated text in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I intend to create a three.js app that informs the user how bright is the light few years ago. The HTML code I used to create it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>How to put GUI in three.js app?</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        
        <!-- MODULE option is more difficult to use in this simple setup:
        <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js"></script>
        -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lil-gui@0.17"></script>

        <script>

            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );
            camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );
            
            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


            const geometry2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 50, 32, 16 );
            const texture2 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://i.imgur.com/P4PQzYk.jpg' );
            const material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: texture2 } );
            const sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );
            
            scene.add( sphere2 );
            sphere2.position.set(100, 0, -500); 

            let colorofsun = new THREE.Color ("rgb( 255, 255, 255)");
            var light = new THREE.PointLight( colorofsun , 2, 5000, 2 );
            light.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
            scene.add( light );
            


          

             function blueDoge(newBlue, newBrightness) 
            {
                const blue = newBlue;
                const bright = newBrightness;
                newBlue = ((-2.4722934782608703 * Math.pow(10, -11)) * blue) + 1;
                newBrightness = ((-6.52173913043478 * Math.pow(10, -11)) * blue) + 0.7;
                light.color.setRGB(1, 1, newBlue);
                light.intensity = 4 * newBrightness;
                console.log("Doge's brightness is " + ((100 * newBrightness) + 30) + " percent of the current value " + blue + " years ago.");

            }
            
            blueDoge(0, 0);

            const GUI = lil.GUI;
            const gui = new GUI();

            const params = {
              green: 0          
            }

            const folderDoge = gui.addFolder( 'Years ago' );
            folderDoge.add( params, 'green', 0, 4600000000, 10000000).onChange( blueDoge );
            folderDoge.open();



            const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.update();

            function animate() 
            {
                sphere2.rotation.x += 0.00;
                sphere2.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            };
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I was able to run the code but currently, the only technique I know to inform the user how bright the light is few years ago is by via `console.log` function, which is not good.

[image: console.log]

How do we show the user how bright the light is few years ago using three.js? A simple overlay display would suffice and any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your calculations for the previous light levels are correct, you can do this with some html, css and javascript (making use of `document.getElementById`).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>How to put GUI in three.js app?</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="lightlevel"></p>
        <style>
          p {
            position: absolute; /*important that the position is absolute*/
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%; /*change to fit your needs*/
          }
        </style>
    
        <!-- Add rest of body here (only alter the function below:) -->

        <script>
           function blueDoge(newBlue, newBrightness) 
            {
                const blue = newBlue;
                const bright = newBrightness;
                newBlue = ((-2.4722934782608703 * Math.pow(10, -11)) * blue) + 1;
                newBrightness = ((-6.52173913043478 * Math.pow(10, -11)) * blue) + 0.7;
                light.color.setRGB(1, 1, newBlue);
                light.intensity = 4 * newBrightness;
                document.getElementById(lightlevel).innerHTML = "Doge's brightness is " + ((100 * newBrightness) + 30) + " percent of the current value " + blue + " years ago.";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Only alter the `blueDoge` function in your code, it is the only thing that needs to be changed.

Comment: I never thought it would be this straightforward. This is quite helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that works after I accepted the answer above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>How to put GUI in three.js app?</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

         <p id="lightlevel"></p>
        <style>
          p {
            position: absolute; /*important that the position is absolute*/
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%; /*change to fit your needs*/
            color: white;
          }
        </style>
        
        <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        
        <!-- MODULE option is more difficult to use in this simple setup:
        <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js"></script>
        -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lil-gui@0.17"></script>

        <script>

            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );
            camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );
            
            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


            const geometry2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 50, 32, 16 );
            const texture2 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://i.imgur.com/P4PQzYk.jpg' );
            const material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: texture2 } );
            const sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );
            
            scene.add( sphere2 );
            sphere2.position.set(100, 0, -500); 

            let colorofsun = new THREE.Color ("rgb( 255, 255, 255)");
            var light = new THREE.PointLight( colorofsun , 2, 5000, 2 );
            light.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
            scene.add( light );
            


          

             function blueDoge(newBlue, newBrightness) 
            {
                const blue = newBlue;
                const bright = newBrightness;
                newBlue = ((-2.4722934782608703 * Math.pow(10, -11)) * blue) + 1;
                newBrightness = ((-6.52173913043478 * Math.pow(10, -11)) * blue) + 0.7;
                light.color.setRGB(1, 1, newBlue);
                light.intensity = 4 * newBrightness;
                document.getElementById("lightlevel").innerHTML = "Doge's brightness is " + ((100 * newBrightness) + 30) + " percent of the current value " + blue + " years ago.";

            }
            
            blueDoge(0, 0);

            const GUI = lil.GUI;
            const gui = new GUI();

            const params = {
              green: 0          
            }

            const folderDoge = gui.addFolder( 'Years ago' );
            folderDoge.add( params, 'green', 0, 4600000000, 10000000).onChange( blueDoge );
            folderDoge.open();



            const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.update();

            function animate() 
            {
                sphere2.rotation.x += 0.00;
                sphere2.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            };
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Feel free to test it!